# Discord Bot JS V12 client on message Reaction

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have put this code in my `index.js`, but it only works with new messages after the bot has started.

And with an old message sent before the start of the bot, it doesn't work. He just ignores that message.

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (user.bot) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channelverify) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name == checkemoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(inwonerrole);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(whitelistrole);
            }
        }else {
            return;
        }
    });
    
    client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channelverify) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name == checkemoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(inwonerrole);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(whitelistrole);
            }
        }else {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check if you have `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intents enabled in your client initialization.

Answer (score 1):

`messageReactionAdd` event is only fired with cached messages -- So old messages' reactions won't get fired

But you can fetch them - So they're cached

```
/*
TextChannel = The channel which messages you want to get
*/
TextChannel.messages.fetch()
```

This will make discord.js cache the messages of the channel; You don't need to save it in a variable or constant (The fetching must be done before the `client.on`)

After caching all channel's messages the event will fire with them; since they're cached.

Comment: Your first line `messageReactionAdd event is only fired with cached messages -- So old messages' reactions won't get fired` is false information. It should work even if the bot is getting restarted. The issue might be something with intents, but OP didn't put the rest of his code in his/her post so we won't know for sure.

Comment: At first I thought it was an intents issue, but without intents it wouldn't fire even with new messages

Comment: (Edit) That is true, but `GUILD_MESSAGES` and `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` are both different intents. Without `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`, message events still work fine even if you don't have the reactions intents enabled (and vice versa), i've checked.

Comment: @node_modules uncached messages do not receive the reaction events

Comment: See the [description](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) of the event

Comment: @MrMythical I've checked more like three times. For me it does work. I even completely closed my bot and started to react on messages sent weeks and even months ago. I can show it to you by screen capture

Comment: You are probably caching messages in some point of the code, but the docs say it, the event only fires reactions of cached messages - Plus you can deduct it by logic

Comment: @tenesiss No caching involved, at least not on my side. Maybe the framework does it, but I don't think it's caching all messages even when I start a fresh session, who knows. But I use Discord V13, so maybe that could be the difference.